# Vuejs can't access refs from component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to get the canvas element which is inside a template of a component, found great documentations for vuejs1 but not for vuejs2 where "ref" is the only way to get the element. I am getting the object though, but when I try to access the variable it is undefined.

### HTML

```html
<div id="app>
  <template id="image-capture">
    <div class="row" >
      <canvas ref="icanvas" ></canvas>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

### JS

```js
const ic = {
  template: '#image-capture' ,
   
  created () {
    console.log(this.$refs); //this returns object
    console.log(this.$refs.icanvas); // but this is undefined
  }
}

const routes = [
  { path: '/ic', component:   ic},
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes 
})

 new Vue({
  router,
   }).

$mount('#app')
```

I need to get the icanvas element.

[image: here is console log]

Comment: Give the canvas an ID and use this: `this.$el.querySelector('#elementID')`

Comment: no absolutely not :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `created` is fired before the template is processed.
You can find more details here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

You should be able to access the $refs on the `mounted` event

```
mounted: function() {
    console.log(this.$refs.icanvas);
},
```

Comment: That's right. Unfortunately, it's still an issue if your `ref`is on a `v-for`element. The DOM isn't acctualy eable to access this `ref` when `mounted`hook is fired. Any suggestion about this ? Thanks !

Comment: @BrownBe, there is still no answers. Here is the [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2044)

Comment: @BrownBe, check my answer, maybe it can solve your problems.

Comment: Why this answer was marked as accepted? Computed can find refs

Comment: Try using it with [this.nextTick()](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) if it still doesn't work.

Comment: In the case of using a `v-for`, I had to use  `await nextTick()` during the `async mounted()` lifecycle without any arguments to make it work. Otherwise, it was not working correctly.

Answer (score 29):

You can use $nextTick() function, code inside $nextTick() will run after DOM update.

```
this.$nextTick(function () {

    console.log(this.$refs.ANY_COMPONENT_REF)

})
```

Comment: no, this doesn't work same issue as the OP described in my case. I have some refs in the component, on mounted am trying to animate the refs but theyre coming out as "undefined". I have no v-for or v-if or any other blockers in the component that would case an issue.

Comment: This DOES work, even if you're still getting the issue inside the mounted hook. Try:

async mounted() { await this.$nextTick(); console.log(this.$refs.myElement) }

Answer (score 13):

i had the exact same issue, in my case i solved it by accessing the ref in the method that changes the v-if with nextTick.

```
methods: {
open() {
  this.show = true; //v-if condition
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      this.titleWidth = this.$refs.titleBg.clientWidth - 30;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

@Dan Levin 's answer works.

```
methods: {
fecthData() {
    this.data ={ ... }; // assume the fetched data have changed DOM here.

    this.$nextTick(() => {
      console.log(this.$refs); // returns obj
      console.log(this.$refs.target); // returns el
    });
}
```

this works also with v-for.

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this error. The way i fixed this issue was by getting the *refs* in the updated hook. See my example below.

In my data object I have an empty array called 'products'.

```
data() {
    return {
        products: []
    }
}
```

In the updated hook I check if any refs are found. If not then nothing will happen. Then when there are products found, the script will continue. Next time Vue will come into the updated hook again, your script won't be triggerd again because now the length of the products array is bigger than one (if any refs could be found of course).

```
updated() {
    let products = this.$refs.products;
    if (!products || this.products.length > 0) return;

    this.products = products;
    // run your logic here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved for me, as well without needing the `$nextTick()` method above, which also works.

Comment: I do not know what changed. There is nothing working with recognized update() next to e.g. mounted(). I am using vuejs3.

Answer (score 0):

In may case, I use `v-for` like:

```
<li class="list__item" v-for="(item,index) in pubList" :key="index">
   <img
      class="list__img lazy_image"
      ref="lazyImages"
    >
</li>
```

And

```
 //pubList is from ajax
 props: ['pubList'],
```

In this case, I solve this by:

```
  watch: {
    'pubList': {
        handler:function(newArray) {
             if(newArray.length===0){
                return
              }
             this.$nextTick(function() {
               console.log(this.$refs.lazyImages)
             })
          },
       immediate:true
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To point at vue instance to self variable worked for me, [info source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47549743/9485417)

```
created() {
    let self = this;
    console.log(self.$refs.icanvas);
},
```