# communicating with data or methods in vue and addEventListener

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having trouble communicating with my data or methods with this code,

```
created() {
  document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', function( e ) {
    this.myData = e.changedTouches[ 0 ].screenY
  }
}
```

I'm guessing that it's because of the function's scope, .this doesn't work inside the function, but then how do I communicate with my data or activate any methods outside of the event listener function then?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are right this is happening because of `this` binding inside the callback which is not pointing the vue instance

To solve this problem define a variable `var self = this` in the created hook pointing the vue instance and reference the data property using `self` inside the callback

```
created() {
  var self = this;
  document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', function( e ) {
    self.myData = e.changedTouches[ 0 ].screenY
  })
}
```

Now since the callback has a closure over the variable `self` it references the vue instance when it gets invoked

As an alternative you can use arrow functions which bind `this` lexically as follows

```
created() {
  document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', ( e ) => {
    this.myData = e.changedTouches[ 0 ].screenY
  })
}
```

Comment: I feel quite dumb after this... I actually went and try passing this into the function, and having all sorts of errors, etc etc... When I can just read a var outside. Thanks for your help! Oh wow, arrow functions are actually even better, I didn't know it can be used this way. Nice!

Comment: Was difficult to find the solution, thanks!!

Comment: Using the arrow function solved my problem