# Vue.js - Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following but I get error `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`:

```
 var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#root',
        data: {
            posts: [],
            newPost: {}
        },
        createPost: function() {
               axios.post("api/posts/create", this.newPost).then(function (response) {
                    this.posts.push(response.data);
                })
        }
 });
```

In my network tab in chrome dev tools I can see response.data is clearly an object:

```
{
  "id": 131,
  "postContent": "<p>test</p>\n",
}
```

So why I'm i getting this error?

Comment: where did you initialized `this.posts`?

Comment: Your posts array variable is inside data. So I think you should use this.data.posts.push() instead of this.posts.push()

Comment: Just answered it here....have a look....https://stackoverflow.com/q/47549346/7814783

Comment: @VamsiKrishna you are right. I added the `=>` syntax and now It works. Thanks.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Why does the arrow function not work in IE11? I'm using webpack and bundling the javascript using the `"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",`  and ` "es6-promise": "^4.1.1",`.

Answer (score 7):

That's because `this` context is assigned incorrectly which means that `this` does not point on the Vue component. To solve this problem, you can use `=>` syntax which simply means a sophisticated way of `this self = this` outside of the target callback.

```
createPost: function() {
  axios.post("api/posts/create", this.newPost).then((response) => {
     this.posts.push(response.data);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As **IzumiSy** said, this very common problem when using axios or even setTimeout function. You can use es6 arrow synax, create temporary local variable with vm or bind it to the function.

ES6

```
createPost: function() {
 axios.post("api/posts/create", this.newPost).then((response) => {
    this.posts.push(response.data);
 })
}
```

Temporary variable

```
createPost: function() {
let vm = this;
  axios.post("api/posts/create", this.newPost).then(function (response) {
     vm.posts.push(response.data);
  })
}
```

Binding

```
createPost: function() {
  axios.post("api/posts/create", this.newPost).then(function (response) {
     this.posts.push(response.data);
  }.bind(this))
}
```