# VueJS components ref is undefined at all stages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm learning VueJS using it with a rails app and I'm having issues trying to access a component from a parent component. It's possible I'm doing this wrong but I can't figure out what the problem is.

I've tried to boil down my problem to a simple html example:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <outer>
        <div>
          <form>
            <inner ref="testref"><input/></inner>
          </form>
        </div>
      </outer>
    </div>
    <script>
      let inner = Vue.component('inner', {
        template: `
          <div>
            <span hidden="true"><slot></slot></span>
            <input v-model="searchText" />
          </div>
        `,
        props: ['placeholder'],
        data: function() {
          return {
            searchText: this.placeholder
          }
        }
      })
      let outer = Vue.component('outer', {
        template: `
          <div>
            <h3 v-on:click="testos">Hello: {{ client_id }}</h3>
            <slot></slot>
          </div>
        `,
        data: function() {
          console.log('data', this.$refs.testref)
          return {
            client_id: ''
          }
        },
        mounted: function() {
          console.log('mounted', this.$refs.testref)
        },
        methods: {
          testos: function() {
            console.log('method', this.$refs.testref)
          }
        }
      })
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: {
          'inner': inner,
          'outer': outer
        }
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get the following console logs:

```html
data undefined
mounted undefined
method undefined
```

I've tried to follow the syntax in https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref, but I've also tried using `:ref` instead of `ref` and it doesn't work any better.

I get that there is "ref registration timing" complication even if I don't fully understand it. However shouldn't the timing be good when clicking on the H3 ? I was hoping it'd be even resolved by `mounted` like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40884455/2730032.

**Bonus question :** My question is really about how ref works. However I do have a more general problem that might benefit with advice not using ref.

I have an `inner` component I'm pleased with that wraps an input field for a client_id with a search field that gives some select-like options from an API and sets the input field client_id to the selected option. I want to re-use that `inner` component in an `outer` component that would use the client_id (whenever it is changed by `inner`) to call an API and fill a bunch of other form fields in the `outer` component (those fields being given with `inner` to `outer` through slots). If that makes any sense.

I figured the best way to do that is put the client_id as a data field of `inner` and have `outer` access it through `ref`. So here I am trying to get `ref` to work.

**EDIT1:** There was a copy mistake, sorry about that. The test1 tag was from a previous version. But I get the problem regardless.

**EDIT2:** I accepted Roy J second answer because I feel it best answers the question and even though it is not good design it's probably a valid solution for some people. However in my actual implementation I used Roy J first answer  and anyone reading this question probably should too (I also managed to add `inner` to `outer`'s template in order to avoid using `app`).

Comment: As a general rule, don't look inside of components, particularly don't try to look at them in the view to get useful things out. That's the problem frameworks are intended to solve. Manage the data so that the units that need it have access to it. It may be that the inner component receives the data as a prop, rather than owning it, and sends events when it should change.

Comment: Your initial problem is that the `ref` is defined in the root Vue instance, not as part of either component. You're trying to access it as if it belonged to the `outer` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only reason you weren't able to use your `ref` was that it was defined in the parent, you *can* go up to `$parent` and use its `refs`. Note that this makes `outer` depend on (entangled with) the structure of `inner` and the presence of a `ref` to get to it. It is bad design, but it is the smallest change to the code you have to get it to do what you're trying to do.

```js
const inner = Vue.component('inner', {
  template: `
          <div>
            <span hidden="true"><slot></slot></span>
            <input v-model="searchText" />
          </div>
        `,
  props: ['placeholder'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      searchText: this.placeholder
    }
  }
});
const outer = Vue.component('outer', {
  template: `
          <div>
            <h3 v-on:click="testos">Hello: {{ client_id }}</h3>
            <slot></slot>
          </div>
        `,
  data: function() {
    return {
      client_id: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    testos: function() {
      this.client_id = this.$parent.$refs.testref.searchText;    
      console.log('method', this.client_id);
    }
  }

})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'inner': inner,
    'outer': outer
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <outer>
    <div>
      <form>
        <inner ref="testref"></inner>
      </form>
    </div>
  </outer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer that works and does exactly what is asked. I accepted it even though it's "bad design" but in my question I also suggest your other answer. Anyone reading this should check it out below.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ref` is defined as part of your root-level template. You are trying to access it from `outer`, but it is not defined there, so it never shows up.

In general, `ref`s are an exceptional situation. You should treat them as a last resort, when you really need to know something about the state of the DOM, not when you need to share data.

The proper way to share data is to have it owned by a common ancestor of the components that need to use it. That may be a store like Vuex, or the root instance, for example.

I have written up how your example code might work if the root instance owned `client_id` and shared it down with `outer` and `inner`. In passing to `inner`, I include the [`.sync` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) for clean handling of updates.

I define `searchText` as a settable computed that emits the update event that triggers `sync`, so that you can still `v-model="searchText"`.

```js
const inner = Vue.component('inner', {
  template: `
          <div>
            <span hidden="true"><slot></slot></span>
            <input v-model="searchText" />
          </div>
        `,
  props: ['placeholder'],
  computed: {
    searchText: {
      get() { return this.placeholder; },
      set(newValue) { this.$emit('update:placeholder', newValue); }
    }
  }
});
const outer = Vue.component('outer', {
  template: `
          <div>
            <h3 v-on:click="testos">Hello: {{ client_id }}</h3>
            <slot></slot>
          </div>
        `,
  props: ['client_id'],
  methods: {
    testos() {
      console.log("Yes, client_id is", this.client_id);
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    client_id: 'Initial Client ID'
  },
  components: {
    'inner': inner,
    'outer': outer
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <outer :client_id="client_id">
    <div>
      <form>
        <inner :placeholder.sync="client_id"></inner>
      </form>
    </div>
  </outer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks: this seems to work, I'll probably accept it as the answer if nobody has a better one. Just a couple of questions though:

1) My `inner` component works as a standalone in many other places, isn't there a way without "polluting" it with an emit that is needed only in one case ? 

2) Also I was hoping since `inner` is in `outer`'s slot I wouldn't have to make the info travel all the way up to app, is the only alternative really using Vuex?

Comment: If  the data for `inner` normally isn't shared, you could make a non-sharing version by wrapping the sharing version in a component that owns the data item. You _could_ use [slot scope](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) to pass an event bus to `inner` and have it emit on that bus to communicate with its slot-parent. (And you could make a non-sharing wrapper for that as well.) It is important to preserve encapsulation. Otherwise it becomes hard to understand what you've built.

Answer (score 0):

Expounding upon Roy's comment, use [the sync modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) if you need 2-way data binding of a property. In your case, you do. The child needs to be able to update the property and let the parent know of the change. There's actually magic under the hood where the value is a callback function which returns the value of the child and the parent updates the variable its self.

As far as why your `ref` isn't working - the child component hadn't been created even though the parent had been mounted. This is due to how the `._render()` method works in VueJS. So if you need to utilize a ref on a custom component that is a child, you need to catch the change in the `next tick`:

```
mounted: function() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
      console.log(this.$refs.testref)
  })
}
```

Finally, and maybe just a bad copy job, you have a syntax error in your code:

```
<inner ref="testref"><inner/></test1>
```

That closing tag `</test1>` matches nothing and will throw a parser error.

All the above should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for catching my typo but this.$nextTick doesn't work either.